# Developing in MonoDroid - prospect of moving to BlackBerry 10

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.android, blackberry-10

We have some MonoDroid code which we have structured to facilitate development of equivalent apps in Android, iOS (via MonoTouch) and WP7; using a single underlying library for the business logic.

We have customer demand to move our app into BlackBerry-10.  When I read about BlackBerry-10 supporting a Android Apps I got excited.  I've read a bit more from the ["Runtime for Android apps"](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/Mastertopic_1849583_11.html) page. Am I right in assuming this won't work with an APK file produced from Mono for Android?

In which case is anyone aware of a way of building a BlackBerry-10 app to embed our established C# business logic?  Or how big a challenge would it be for someone to produce the required runtime for mono on BlackBerry-10 - is that the sort of thing that could be funded by a community effort? It works out cheaper than 10 companies having to completely port their App to BlackBerry-10.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758649/is-there-any-kind-of-solution-to-develop-blackberry-apps-in-c-sharp-like-mono-fo

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your vote on Xamarin's UserVoice page:

http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions/suggestions/2617326-monoblackberry

Xamarin has not responded, so I hope that we can get some feedback on their plans.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your mono android .apk file into blackberry .bar file. Online tool is available for this you can check that if your .apk file run on BB10 or not?

Link to check apk file : https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/

Answer (score 0):

There is another project [dot42](http://www.dot42.com), compiling c# directly to  Android dex apps without any runtime requirements such as Mono.