# Is there any kind of solution to develop Blackberry Apps in C# like Mono for Android or Monotouch?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have one application that has been ported to Android and iOS using Xamarin solutions Mono for Android and MonoTouch. This has been made because in this way I can use the same encryption libraries to connect all these platforms with a C# web service that decrypt the received data without the need of HTTPS.

Is there any solution using C# that can be ported to Blackberry? Would the Blackberry 10 OS capability yo port Android apps a solution for this problem?

BTW do not asnwer me with the solution of migrating to a HTTPS capable web service.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8):

Answer is yes and no.

Yes. Generally, you can port Android apps to Blackberry 10. You can use [provided tools](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/) to check for compatibility.

But, unfortunately you cannot port Mono for Android apps to BB 10 yet. Because

> Apps that utilize native code bundled into their APK file

is currently [not supported by BB 10](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html) which is the way [how Mono for Android works](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/guides/advanced_topics/architecture), this is the 'No` answer.

However, good news is there is a cool [open source work](http://burningsoda.com/software/monoberry/) to allow you develop native BB 10 apps in C#.

Comment: Has this situation changed with the recent support for Jellybean in BB  10.2.1?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not yet, but there is mono runtime for Blackberry 10, you can check http://burningsoda.com/software/monoberry/

hopefully, xamarin forms is available for blackberry 10 in the future.